# Old Wiring for new light fixture installation (no ground?)

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, dimmer-switch

Replacing and old light with a new light and when I took out the old light old I was concerned about the wiring and that it may not be safe since the previous lights grounding wire was not attached to anything.

This light was and still will be on a dimmer switch.

Included pictures of switch wiring and light.

Thanks for the help!
[image: Dimmer Gang and wiring]

[image: Light Gang and Wiring]

Answer (score 4):

### Land the grounding wire for the light on a pigtail from the box grounding screw

It appears that the power feed into the ceiling box was run in conduit from the presence of the bushing on the pancake box and the writing on the incoming neutral, with an old-style switch loop run from the ceiling to the wall-box using a /2 NM cable.

Given this, what you need to do is thread a 10-32 screw into the matching tapped hole on the back of the box, then run a pigtail from that to the junction of the grounding wire for the switch loop and the grounding wire from the fixture.  (You can use a premade screw-and-pigtail combination for this if you wish.)